# Can I control wind area?

Tags: physics

I want to make animation of wind that blows text in particles from top to bottom, but the wind blows the whole text. I think wind applies everywhere. How to control its area to blow specific things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [falloff for the force field](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/physics/force_fields/introduction.html#falloff) which will specify the shape of the areas where it will make the effect.

In the force field options (in the [Properties editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/editors/properties_editor.html)) find *Faloff* area and check *Tube* instead of *Sphere*, selected by default. This will make force field affect in the areas which fall in that shape while with *Sphere* it affects radially in all directions.
Then enable *Maximum*, just below the *Tube* option; this will ensure the force field doesn't affect all the particles in the given area.

[image: screenshot-wind-force-field-settings-first]

If testing this now, force field will affect all the particles in the given direction up to the specified minimum:

[image: GIF force field affecting all the particles in the given direction]

*Particles are red icospheres; blue line in the middle is the plane which shows maximum area of the force field effect; partially transparent blueish cylinder shows force field shape itself.*

This is however not what is desired; the force field affects up to the certain area, *but* to all the particles, reaching its minimum distance. To make it affect only particles within its shape of effect enable *Maximum* in the *Radial* settings:

[image: screenshot-force-field-radial-settings]

With that, force field will affect particles up to the certain area (shown as blue line) and within certain area of the tube (in this case) shape.

[image: GIF-wind-force-field-affects-only-within-its-shape]

Answer (score -3):

[image] Click on the wind and go to the right hand properties panel and u can find various settings. In the strength u can lower the wind etc.